# python2 regexp and connect the white list

Tags: regex, xml, python-2.6

How to connect the white list that the values which are in it weren't processed?
How to apply regex validation of 'mail' that it wasn't removed bad 'mails'?
To print each 'mail' result since a new line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
from xml.dom.minidom import *
xml = parse('test.xml')
name = xml.getElementsByTagName('mail')
mail = set()
for node in name:
    mail.add(node.childNodes[0].data.encode('utf-8'))
    result = re.findall(r'(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})',str)
print "\n".result.group(0)
```

Comment: What's in `'test.xml'`?